# Matching double quotes in SPARQL query in Virtuoso

Tags: regex, sparql, quotes, virtuoso

I need to get a SPARQL query that matches double quotes in Virtuoso graph. I use such query:

```
SELECT distinct ?o
FROM <http://graph>
WHERE
{
    ?s ?p ?o.
}
```

It returns me a column with such values:

```
http://some.prefix/Symbol
"abcd"
```

I need to match only second value (`"abcd"`). I tried to add such filter to `WHERE` clause:

```
FILTER regex(str(?o), "\"")
```

But it returns no results. I also tried `'"'` as a second parameter to regex, and some other things. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"abcd"` is a literal of four characters. It does not include the `""`; these are the string delimiters and do not form part of the string.

```
FILTER isLiteral(?o)
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Since your filter is not working, `"abcd"` does not have a double quote in it. It's a string literal. Not sure what type it is; so you can use --

```
select ?type where { "abcd" a ?type }
```

-- to get its type. You can then use that type as a filter in your query as:

```
SELECT distinct ?o
FROM <http://graph>
WHERE
{
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?o a <whatever type you received in the previous query> .
}
```

Comment: There is a difference when the rdfs:Class as recorded with `rdf:type` (or keyword `a`) and datatype of a literal. "?o a ..." does not return the datatype. Try DATATYPE(?o) but this is not not necessary as `isLiteral` tests for literals of any datatype.

Comment: Agreed. isLiteral() is a better way to do this.